# Published app crashing due to error "Cannot find MainActivity"

Tags: android, android-layout

I published app at the Market and I keep getting error:

```
Exception class: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Source method: Resources.getValue()

 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.xxx.yyy/com.xxx.yyy.MainActivity}:
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f45001c
```

The app has the splash image which starts the `MainActivity`. This activity loads the XML file `main.xml`. Nothing unusual. When I load the app in all my phones, I get no error. The same is with all emulators.

It occurred to me that the error may be because of the resource folders in the `/res` dir. I have the following layout folders (look at the image). I have to have many layout folders as the layout of the MainActivity is such that I have to position its elements at special X and Y coordinates at the special distance from top and left margin.

[image]

It looks like the app tries to load MainActivity. Then it tries to load the layout file `main.xml` and it fails there.

Any suggestions???

Thanks in advdnce

Comment: Try deleting the `gen` directory and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Did u add the Activity in manifest file??

Comment: @PeterKnego I did what you said but the error is still there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: So the apk that you built works if you install it directly on the phone, but when you upload to market it stops working?

Comment: No, it does not stop working all the time, but sometimes. I have approx 100+ downloads a day and approx 20ish errors mentioned here. PS. it works OK on all my phones and that's why I cannot trace this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check that you have default versions for all your resources and layouts stored in `layout` and `drawable`. Maybe there is a device that tries to take a resource from `layout-large-hdpi` and since this folder does not exist, it tries to find the resource in `layout`, fails and throws the exception.

At least, it would explain why you don't get the exception on your devices.

Comment: Hm, good point. I will try that. so you're saying that I would get the same error if some image does not have its default file in the /drawable? This is a new thing to me as I've never read that I have to take care about that.

Comment: It makes sense. Obviously, a device should not use resources from a profile that doesn't match. And if there is no matching profile and no default version of the required resource, crashing seems like a valid option. :)

Comment: The error is still there. Any other suggestions? Maybe I miss some layout folder - what do you think?

Comment: I'd suggest you to find out which resource has the ID `#0x7f45001c` and make sure that it is available for every possible configuration.

Comment: It's an ID for the layout MainActivity. That's why I mentioned layout folder structures. Does the structure from the image above have any missing elements in your opinion?

Comment: Folder structure is irrelevant. Do you have a copy of this layout in the `layout` folder?

Comment: Yes I have. If mobile screen cannot find any declared layout, it will look for it in the /res/layout folder.

Comment: I'm afraid, I'm out of ideas. Could you publish the expanded directory tree of the `res` folder?

Comment: The image shows all folders in /res. Do you want to see all the files in all the folders?